# hibernate, mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, mysql-error-1093

i have the following hql query:

```
UPDATE TaskAssessment taskAssessment 
SET taskAssessment.activeFlag = false 
WHERE taskAssessment IN 
(
SELECT taskAssessment2 
FROM TaskAssessment taskAssessment2 
Where taskAssessment2.activeFlag = true 
AND taskAssessment2.patient.id 
AND taskAssessment2.needsLevel.careNeed = :careNeed
)
```

but its giving me errors:

```
You can't specify target table 'TASK_ASSESSMENT' for update in FROM clause
```

could anyone help me to correct the query for mysql and hibernate. thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: i saw it, but when i try that it says unexpected ( in the query !

Comment: @user582862: Can you post what you've already tried?

Comment: i tried this: UPDATE TaskAssessment taskAssessment SET taskAssessment.activeFlag = false WHERE taskAssessment IN ( SELECT taskAssessment2 FROM (SELECT any FROM TaskAssessment any) taskAssessment2 Where taskAssessment2.activeFlag = true AND taskAssessment2.patient.id AND taskAssessment2.needsLevel.careNeed = :careNeed)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve `You can't specify target table 'TASK_ASSESSMENT' for update in FROM clause`,  rewrite the query to use `JOIN` instead of `IN` (in mysql you need to write something like this):

```
UPDATE TaskAssessment a
INNER JOIN TaskAssessment a2 ON (a2.id = a.id)
SET a.activeFlag = 0  
WHERE a2.active_flag = 1 AND 
a2.patient_id = :patient_id AND a2.needsLevel_careNeed = :careNeed
```

Comment: tried this: UPDATE TaskAssessment taskAssessment INNER JOIN TaskAssessment taskAssessment2 ON (taskAssessment.id = taskAssessment2.id) SET taskAssessment.activeFlag = false Where taskAssessment2.activeFlag = true AND taskAssessment2.patient.id = :patientId AND taskAssessment2.needsLevel.careNeed = :careNeed

Comment: and it didnt work. gives error: expecting "set", found 'INNER'

Comment: It's mysql syntax, not hql. To make it work you need to use `CreateSQLQuery` + `executeUpdate`. I'm not sure if you can use join + update in hql.

Comment: if you kindly look at the heading it mentions hibernate and yes i am working with hql, so i need help with hql rather than just simple mysql query.